# quisiera saber como sacar las consultas para mi base de datos según las siguientes instrucciones

Tags: mysql

las consultas serian conforme lo que pide la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He revertido la edición. Por favor DAVID, no bandalices tu publicación. Aunque la pregunta haya sido cerrada, tiene una respuesta, y borrando todo a algo sin sentido pierde el poco contexto y la poca calidad que ya tenía tu pregunta. Si quieres mejorarla hazlo, si quieres eliminarla, también puedes hacerlo, pero no la pongas PEOR que como ya está.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

David pudo identiticar tres tablas: CLIENTES, PEDIDOS, COMERCIAL.
Para que sea hecho una consulta mejor es necessário que se conosca la estructura de las tablas.

Sigue um exemplo de cada iten solicitado:

TABLA: CLIENTES, PEDIDOS, COMERCIAL

```
1 - SELECT identificado, nombre, primer_apellido
    FROM CLIENTES
    WHERE segun_apellido IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY primer_apellido,nombre
    
2 -SELECT nombre 
   FROM CLIENTES
   WHERE nombre NOT LIKE 'A%' 
   ORDER BY nombre

3 - // No ha sido definido el intervalo del mayor valor
    SELECT * 
    FROM PEDIDOS
    WHERE valor BETWEEN  1.00 AND 9.999
    ORDER BY VALOR DESC
    
4 - Es necesário conocer las tablas de clientes y pedidos

5 - Es necesário conocer las tablas de clientes y pedidos

6 - Es necessário conocer las clientes ,pedidos y comercial
```

Comment: No puedes contestar ya que no hay ni el mas mínimo intento por parte del usuario que plantea la pregunta, le estas haciendo la tarea.